# Pyinstaller: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools._distutils'

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I try to package a Python script into an excutable file using Pyinstaller. But I when I run it on machine (Windows 10), the following problem occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "StellaVC.py", line 4, in <module>
    import librosa
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "librosa\__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "librosa\_cache.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "joblib\__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "joblib\memory.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "joblib\_store_backends.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "joblib\backports.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "_distutils_hack\__init__.py", line 88, in create_module
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "setuptools\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "_distutils_hack\__init__.py", line 88, in create_module
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools._distutils'
[7260] Failed to execute script 'StellaVC' due to unhandled exception!
```

I have checked `site-packages` and `setuptool._distutils` does exist. I've also tried `hidden-import`, but it does not work.

This is the pip list:

```
PS D:\Desktop\StellaVoiceChanger> pip list
Package                   Version
------------------------- ---------
altgraph                  0.17.3
appdirs                   1.4.4
audioread                 3.0.0
certifi                   2022.9.24
cffi                      1.15.1
charset-normalizer        2.1.1
Cython                    0.29.21
decorator                 5.1.1
future                    0.18.2
idna                      3.4
joblib                    1.2.0
librosa                   0.8.0
llvmlite                  0.39.1
numba                     0.56.3
numpy                     1.21.6
packaging                 21.3
pefile                    2022.5.30
pip                       22.2.2
pooch                     1.6.0
pycparser                 2.21
pyinstaller               5.5
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2022.10
pyparsing                 3.0.9
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0
requests                  2.28.1
resampy                   0.4.2
scikit-learn              1.1.2
scipy                     1.9.2
setuptools                65.3.0
soundfile                 0.11.0
threadpoolctl             3.1.0
torch                     1.12.1
torchaudio                0.12.1
typing_extensions         4.4.0
urllib3                   1.26.12
wheel                     0.37.1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error might be related with the installed version of `setuptools`. Can you add the output of `pip list` to your question?

Comment: I still don't figure out the problem after trying many methods. But I get my exe file to work anyway by creating another virtual environment and copy all the packages neccessary to its directory.

Comment: Hope you don't mind this hopefully amusing comment re your [hot Linguistics question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/47898/in-which-situations-or-societies-do-people-not-take-turns-to-speak-in-conversati): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Son,_the_Physicist

Answer (score 0):

as @shakthifuture mentioned [here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2353#issuecomment-684452550)

You can give this a try

```
export SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib
pip3 install [...]
```